# Anticipated OPT: Question regarding work contract

Tags: usa

I am an F-1 student still awaiting arrival of my EAD (Employment Authorization Document Card) for OPT. I have told my potential employer that I can begin work starting on the date I listed in my OPT application, which is in about 3 weeks.

Can I sign an employment contract prior to arrival of the EAD card? with a work start date identical to the start date I requested on my OPT application?

The catch here is I am not sure that the EAD card will arrive on time, as USCIS does not guarantee EAD card arrival by the requested date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sign whatever you want. You cannot work before your EAD.